# Tensorflow image_retraining:retrain in docker is not found

Tags: docker, tensorflow, bazel, pre-trained-model

I'm new with tensorflow but I seem not to understand some stuff.

I installed TF with docker container ( docker run -d -it gcr.io/tensorflow/tensorflow:latest-devel) which creates my container with tensor flow inside.

I'm now trying to use Inceptionv3 ( https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.9/how_tos/image_retraining/index.html) but id doesn't work and I can't find "tensorflow/examples/image_retraining:retrain" anywhere in my container

I thought my installation was the problem so I started a new ubuntu container and tried to install tensor flow,bazel and everything by hand but it's not working.

Does someone have any idea how I could solve my problem.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: `//tensorflow/examples/image_retraining:retrain` is the name of a bazel build target, defined here: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/examples/image_retraining/BUILD . There are instructions on how to build and run it at the tensorflow.org how-to page that you link to. Hope that helps!

Comment: did you figure out of how to run it? Can you please post the solution? Thanks.